# Throw catch in namespaces implementation

Tags: c++, namespaces, try-catch, division, throw

I'm trying to implement a division program with a namespace. I've been really confused as to what to do, as the scope of the assignment is very broad. Could anyone please look at the code and explain why I my throw, catch statement won't catch non integer characters.

It throws the exception when the denomintor is equivalent to 0, but It's not throwing the exception when characters are entered. For example when i input "abc" the program crashes. Could someone also explain a bit about namespaces also please? thank you

Should i be using pointers?...

Namespace File:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

namespace dataChecks
{
  /*
   * parameter numerator
   * parameter denominator
   * returns the double quotient of integer division
   * throws an exception if denominator == 0
   */
 //  bool isvalidInt(string str)


  double quotient( int numerator, int denominator)
  {
     if(denominator == 0)
      throw new string("divide by zero!");
     return static_cast<double>(numerator)/denominator;
   }//end quotient()


  /*
   * parameter str  - the string to evaluate
   * returns true if the string can be parsed
   *   into a valid int
   */
   bool isvalidInt(string str)
   {
     int start = 0;
     int i; //index of one character in the string
     bool valid = true;  // assume a valid string
     bool sign = false;  // assume no sign

     if (str.length()==0)    // if the length of the string is 0
         {
        valid = false;      //set valid to false
        }

     if ((str.at(0) == '+')||(str.at(0) == '-'))  // if the first character is '-' or '+'
     {
         sign = true;
         start= 1;      //set sign to true and start to 1
     }
if ((start && str.length()) == 1)  // if there is not at least one character after the sign
    {
        valid = false;  //set valid to false
    }
i = start;
while( i < str.length() )// check if each character in the string is a digit - isdigit(str.at(i))
    {
        if (isdigit(str.at(i)) == false)
        {
            valid = false;      // if a character is not a digit, set valid to false
        } i++;       // return valid;
    }
return valid;
  }

   /*
    * gets a string from the keyboard
    * throws an exception if the string cannot
    *   be parsed into a valid int
    * otherwise returns the int represented by the string
    */

   int getAnInt()
  {
bool notanint = true;
string svalue;

while (notanint)
{
  try
  {
    // get a string from the
    cin >> svalue;
    // if it is not a valid int throw an exception]

    if (isvalidInt(string (svalue)) == false) throw svalue;
  }
  catch (string e)
  {

    cout<< "Invalid integer [ " << e << " ] - Please reenter: \t";
    // print an error messagecout << "Invalid integer [ " << e << " ] - Please reenter: ";
        continue;
    // send control back to the while statement
  }
  notanint = false;
}
return atoi(svalue.c_str());  // convert to an integer
   }
```

Test File:

```
/*
 * CSIS1600
 * checkDivisionDemo.cpp
 * divide by zero exception
 * uses personal namespace dataChecks
 */

 #include <C:\\CSIS1600\\MyCPPUtils\\dataChecksNamespace.cpp>
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace dataChecks;
 using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int number1; // user-specified numerator
   int number2; // user-specified denominator

   cout << "Enter two integers (end-of-file to end): ";

   // enable user to enter two integers to
    while ( cin >> number1 >> number2 )
    {
  // try block contains code that might throw exception
  // and code that will not execute if an exception occurs
  try
  {
     double result = quotient( number1, number2 );
     cout << "The quotient is: " << result << endl;
  } // end try
  catch ( string *str )
  {
     cout << "Exception occurred: "
        << *str << endl;
  } // end catch
 //     try
 //    {
 //        bool validint1 = isvalidInt(number1, number2);
 //    }
 //     catch ()
       cout << "\nEnter two integers (end-of-file to end): ";
    } // end while

   cout << endl;
 } // end main
```

Comment: for future reference when posting questions on stackoverflow.com: 1. Properly format your code.   2. Exclude irrelevant stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The golden rule when using exceptions in C++ is "throw by value, catch by const reference".

In `quotient()`, when you say

```
throw new string("divide by zero!");
```

you're creating a new string on the heap which is never freed if an exception occurs. Instead, you should just say

```
throw string("divide by zero!");
```

which will stack-allocate a new string instead.

Later, when in your catch block, you should catch by const reference, i.e.

```
catch (const string& str) {
    // ...
}
```

The reason for this is mostly technical: a const reference can bind to an rvalue whereas a mutable reference cannot, and catching by value might require a copy of string.

Or perhaps looking at it another way: the purpose of an exception is to communicate the reason that something failed. That reason is not going to to change once it's happened, so the exception should be treated as `const` after creation.

Comment: I followed your advice, it crashes the program, and the exception i wanted to throw didn't follow.